# On the resource path loading problem in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, web

**This is an example：**

```
http://www.test.com/project/Index_Action!getAll.action
```

This is a project made up of different languages

Under `/project` directory，Provides projects in different languages

It will load the English version first

**Scene**:

1. Under the test environment, Chrome, Firefox, IE, fully loaded resources
2. In the online environment, when Chrome and Firefox access this URL, all the resources are loaded out.

But when Internet Explorer browser access the URL, CSS files and JavaScript files appear

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404  ()

**Problem**：

The URL is missing `/project`

become

```
http://www.test.com/Index_Action!getAll.action
```

**I tried the following：**

1. I added `/project` manually, but IE still ignored it

   ```
   <% String path=request.getContextPath();String basePath=request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/project/";%>
   ```
2. Resource reference:

   `<link href="project/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

In IE, how to prevent the lack of a URL path?

**Response comment area：**

1. Path usage is a relative path
2. The resource cannot be loaded because the path is missing a field.But in other browsers is normal, only IE browser is not normal
3. IE version 9.The cache is clear

Comment: IE shouldn't discard `/project`. Do you have the correct path?

Comment: Then again, it's IE. *shudder*.

Comment: might be the problem of absolute and relative path?
it worked fine in test environment because it might be using absolute path to locate resources, something should've went wrong with relative path. are you sure it is finding resources in the correct resources?
And what is the value of path, actually?

Comment: Please show how you're referencing the files that are not being found.

Comment: What's your IE browser version? According to your code, I create a sample, it seems that everything works well on my side (using IE 11.503.17763.0), please try to clear the cache and browser history then retest your code.